# Can't Integrate deeplinking using branch.io on angular app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, deep-linking, branch.io, socialshare

I have integrated deeplinking using [branch.io](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking) in my angular app.Links are getting generated but for Facebook the content is not getting posted [ showing an error : " Failed to load resource: 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/share/submit?dpr=1' the server responded with a status of 500 ()"] and for Google Plus , the rich content is not displaying.But it's working fine for Twitter and Email.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include additional details on how you are creating the links? Code examples and steps to reproduce would be best.

Comment: @AlexBauer: I had followed this link for deep linking https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking

Comment: This does not appear to be a Branch issue. If you are able to provide examples and replication steps I can investigate further, but right now I suspect this is a problem with how you have implemented Facebook sharing

Comment: Without some type of context or test plan it is difficult to speak to what might be going on here.